# required_without_all validator repeats error message over and over

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm building a roster system as a side project and on one of the pages you can change the regular hours someone works.

On the page I have a checkbox for each day of the week, you can then go through and select the appropriate days that the person works.

They need to work at least one day and so at least one of the checkboxes needs to be checked when submitted.

To test this I am using the [`required_without_all`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-without-all) rule of Laravel's validator.

It works perfectly, however if no boxes are checked it will redirect you back and spit out the same error message 7 times (as there are 7 checkboxes for each day of the week).

I am using custom error messages so this is why the error message is the same, but even if I didn't I wouldn't want a similar error message being repeated over and over.

This is what my validator looks like:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'mondayCheckbox' => 'required_without_all:tuesdayCheckbox,wednesdayCheckbox,thursdayCheckbox,fridayCheckbox,saturdayCheckbox,sundayCheckbox',
            'tuesdayCheckbox' => 'required_without_all:mondayCheckbox,wednesdayCheckbox,thursdayCheckbox,fridayCheckbox,saturdayCheckbox,sundayCheckbox',
            'wednesdayCheckbox' => 'required_without_all:mondayCheckbox,tuesdayCheckbox,thursdayCheckbox,fridayCheckbox,saturdayCheckbox,sundayCheckbox',
            'thursdayCheckbox' => 'required_without_all:mondayCheckbox,tuesdayCheckbox,wednesdayCheckbox,fridayCheckbox,saturdayCheckbox,sundayCheckbox',
            'fridayCheckbox' => 'required_without_all:mondayCheckbox,tuesdayCheckbox,wednesdayCheckbox,thursdayCheckbox,saturdayCheckbox,sundayCheckbox',
            'saturdayCheckbox' => 'required_without_all:mondayCheckbox,tuesdayCheckbox,wednesdayCheckbox,thursdayCheckbox,fridayCheckbox,sundayCheckbox',
            'sundayCheckbox' => 'required_without_all:mondayCheckbox,tuesdayCheckbox,wednesdayCheckbox,thursdayCheckbox,fridayCheckbox,saturdayCheckbox',
            'effective_from' => 'date',
            ], [
            'mondayCheckbox.required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'tuesdayCheckbox.required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'wednesdayCheckbox.required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'thursdayCheckbox.required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'fridayCheckbox.required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'saturdayCheckbox.required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'sundayCheckbox.required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'effective_from.date' => 'You have provided an invalid date for when their hours are effective from!',
            ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
```

So if no boxes are checked on submission, the error `Surely they are working at least one day!` is shown 7 times.

I am displaying the errors on the page like this:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p><b>There were some problems:</b></p>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Is there anyway to only get it to show once?

Comment: What about a small hack? Using jQuery or Javascript, you can set the value of a hidden input if any of the checkbox is checked, else the value is  none. So now in your validator, you can check for the hidden input field and then respond according to that. This would show only one message.

Comment: From the docs for required_without_all: "The field under validation must be present only when all of the other specified fields are not present". So technically this may not be the ideal validator to begin with no? Are you happy going with a custom validator function, an we can take a stab at coimg up with one. That would be way easier a challenge than this here.

Comment: @JilsonThomas I'm open to a small hack, my javascript/jQuery knowledge isn't great - are you able to show me an example of how to do this?
@ihatehandles the `required_without_all` seems to fit pretty well, for example one of the fields needs to be present when none of the other specified fields are. I'm more than happy to take a crack at creating a custom one though - how would you tackle that?

Comment: @James: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wrs89cks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to go around this. Since JS hacks are on the table too, we can also come in from the Blade end and do this (feel free to use your own favourite array manipulation functions):

```
<ul>

    <li>
        {{-- Show error message only once --}}
        @if( $errors->has('mondayCheckbox') || $errors->has('tuesdayCheckbox') ||  $errors->has('wednesdayCheckbox') ||  $errors->has('thursdayCheckbox') ||  $errors->has('fridayCheckbox') ||  $errors->has('saturdayCheckbox') ||  $errors->has('sundayCheckbox') )
            Surely they are working at least one day!
        @endif
    </li>

    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

        {{-- Show other errors not related to the checkboxes --}}
        @unless($error == 'Surely they are working at least one day!')
            <li>
                {{ $error }}
            </li>
        @endunless

    @endforeach
</ul>
```

The other way is to deal with the `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\MessageBag` in your validator with the [After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches) and clean things up there.

Comment: I got this working with an adapted version of @JilsonThomas fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/krg553Lk/, however I really like this approach as it doesn't require an extra hidden field. I've since switched back to using the original validator and this little blade hack. Nice work!

Comment: Thanks, yeah the fiddle was a nice attempt as well. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is late but might help someone with similar problem.
Just apply the rule for a hypothetical field, say, `weekdays` like below.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'weekdays' => 'required_without_all:mondayCheckbox,tuesdayCheckbox,wednesdayCheckbox,thursdayCheckbox,fridayCheckbox,saturdayCheckbox,sundayCheckbox',
            'effective_from' => 'date',
            ], [
            'required_without_all' => 'Surely they are working at least one day!',
            'effective_from.date' => 'You have provided an invalid date for when their hours are effective from!',
            ]);
```

And put all the fields `(mondayCheckbox.... sundayCheckbox)` that you want this rule to be applied after `required_without_all`. And write the validation message for the rule only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_unique($array)` function to remove duplicates from error messages.

Here is the code snippet

```php
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach (array_unique($errors->all()) as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```